# How to authenticate with cookies (security)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

In Express, for "remember me" authentication, I create a JWT token with `user_id`. The encrypted version (based on a secret) of the token gets saved to a cookie on the client. If no session exists, we look for the cookie. If found, to check for authentication, the server decrypts the JWT token from the cookie, and we create a new session based on the id in the token.

My question: Wouldn't this mean that if someone would copy-paste the cookie to their computer, they would be able to pretend to be me? What am I doing wrong security-wise and is there a better way to implement "remember me"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. A session token/cookie is supposed to be kept private. If someone else gets hold of it, they can impersonate you. So you should have a limited lifespan for these tokens, only send them over HTTPS and not use "Remember me" on a shared computer.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be good practice to also encrypt the cookie, so that a user cannot edit the cooke and change its issue date, which is included in the cookie? I think it would be, but have doubts because you then get two layers of encryption: first the JWT token and then the cookie.

Comment: Normally, neither the JWT token nor the session cookie can be altered by the user (the former is signed, the latter is a random number that has to match the server-side database). But neither (nor any additional encryption) protects against someone copying these tokens. They have to be kept private.

Comment: Just a side note - one could also add browser fingerprint https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint into the mix and check if the token in use has been set by a given browser.

Comment: Great, I understand it now! The token expiration date is encrypted and cannot be altered. And of course the cookie needs to be kept private. If you want to add is as an answer, I'll accept it.